# Middleware to redirect users if they type POST route in URL Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

As of now when my user types in a POST route in URL it shows an error saying `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`. I want to write a Middleware which will redirect users if they try to go to any POST route. I have tried doing the following:

I have created a `RedirectIfPOST` Middleware. Here's it's code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class RedirectIfPOST
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        // Redirect if user tries accessing a POST route.

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

In my `Kernel.php` I have added the following line of code to `$routeMiddleware` array:

```
'post' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfPOST::class,
```

And finally in my `web.php` I have grouped all of my `POST` routes inside of my Middleware, like this:

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'post'],function()
{

    Route::post('/signup', 'MainController@signup');

    Route::post('/login', 'MainController@authenticate');

    Route::post('/activate','ActiveController@activate');

});
```

How can I fix this problem so the users will be redirected to main page instead of seeing the error?

**EDIT**

I did the following, just like Sherif Tarek suggested:

I have duplicated my `POST` routes and made the duplicate routes `GET`. Then I grouped the `GET` routes inside of my Middleware. So now my `web.php` looks like this:

```
Route::post('/signup', 'MainController@signup');

Route::post('/login', 'MainController@authenticate');

Route::post('/activate','ActiveController@activate');



Route::group( ['middleware' => 'post'],function()
{

    Route::get('/signup', 'MainController@signup');

    Route::get('/login', 'MainController@authenticate');

    Route::get('/activate','ActiveController@activate');

});
```

This way I redirect users to main page if they try to access POST routes through the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `Route` is checked before the middleware as you can call functions for routing in the middlewares. a possible way to solve your problem is to duplicate your routes but change the method to be `GET` and then assign the middleware to them or you can [redirect](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#redirect-routes) the requests to whatever you want if you chose this way I think having a `RedirectController` will centralize the redirect path or if you want to have a logic.

Comment: great it worked

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the exception is throwing before executing the request dispatch pipeline hence, your middleware function will not be executed. instead of using middleware, you can handle the exceptions to archive your goal

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
   if($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException && $request->isMethod('POST')){
       return redirect('/');
   }
   return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

I have added the above code to laravel `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` file

Comment: I have altered the `render` function in `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` to the one in your example, but i still get the same error while trying to access `POTS` routes. Is there anything else I have to change in code?

Comment: can you please post the Handler.php file content, so we can see is there anything wrong. and make sure you have imported the `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;` statement top of the Handler.php file

Comment: The content is the same, I only changed the body of `render` function. I have added `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;`, but I still get the same error. The answer above solved my problem, but thanks for the help. :)